# Marketing Cloud Journey Builder - different email send hours on weekends

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm trying to set up Journey Builder in following way. There will be some email activities and I should have a delivery window but based on a current day of a week.
From monday to thursday emails can be sent between 8AM - 9 PM.
From friday to sunday emails can be sent between 10AM - 4 PM.

I know there is 'Delivery Window' feature under Delivery Options in Email activity but can it be configured like I described?

Comment: What's the entry source for this journey?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Decision Split in the Journey before each Email Activity that would send contacts in either `Mon-Thu` or `Fri-Sun` path by the attribute value from assisting Data Extension that is going to be populated once per day via SQL  that would have something like -

```
SELECT
DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) AS TodayDate /*it will return full day name, e.g. Thursday*/
FROM [DE_Name]
```

Remember that you would need to create an Attribute Group with that assisting Data Extension in order to use in the Decision Split.

Then you can add Email Activity into each path and set [Send Throttling](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_configure_the_send_email_activity.htm&type=5) setting with the correct [Delivery Window](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_configure_delivery.htm&type=5) time (if you do not see these settings in Delivery Options then navigate to Setup --> Feature Settings --> Email Studio --> Email Optional Feature --> Enable Send Throttling).

There are also options when you can play with [Wait By Attribute Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_wait_for_a_date_based_on_an_attribute_value.htm&type=5) or [Wait Until Date Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_wait_until_a_specific_date.htm&type=5) or simple [Wait by Duration Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_wait_for_a_period_of_time.htm&type=5) once the audience is split into 2 batches.